# How to sleep PHP(Laravel 5.2) in background

Tags: php, multithreading, laravel-5, sleep

I have created an `artisan command` that I want to run immediately after a method called. But the command contains a `sleep();` command. I want to run that **artisan command in background** because the method need to `return` immediately response to user. My sample code is a below:

**In route file**

```
Route::get('test', function(){
    Artisan::queue('close:bidding', ['applicationId' => 1]);
    return 'called close:bidding';
});
```

**In `close:bidding` command**

```
public function handle()
    {
        $appId = $this->argument('applicationId');
        //following code line is making the problem
        sleep(1000 * 10);
        //close bidding after certain close time
        try{
            Application::where('id', $appId)->update(['live_bidding_status' => 'closed']);
        }catch (\PDOException $e){
            $this->info($e->getMessage());//test purpose
        }
        $this->info($appId.":  bid closed after 10 seconds of creation");
    }
```

**Problem** 
When I hit `/test` url the return string `called close:bidding` is being shown after 10 seconds browser loading, because there is a `sleep(10 * 1000)` inside the command.

**What I want** 
I want to run the command in background. I mean when I hit the `/test` url it should immediately show up the `called close:bidding` but `close:bidding` command will be running in background. After 10 seconds it will update the application though the front-end user won't notice anything anything about it.

**Partial Questions**

1. Is it somehow related to `multi threading`?
2. Is it something that cannot be solve using PHP, should I think differently?
3. Is there any way to solve this problem even using Laravel queue?

Comment: May be you can try laravel queue jobs instead command

Comment: Thanks, I will try

Answer (score 7):

Create a job

```
<?php

namespace App\Jobs;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class JobTest implements ShouldQueue
{
    use InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    private $payload = [];
    public function __construct($payload)
    {
        $this->payload = $payload;
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        $appId = $this->payload('applicationId');
        //following code line is making the problem
        sleep(1000 * 10);
    }
}
```

To push job background queue

```
Route::get('test', function(){
    dispatch((new JobTest)->onQueue('queue_name'));
    return 'called close:bidding';
});
```

At this state we have job and you dispath the job to the queue. But it not processed yet. We need queue listener or worker to process those job in background

```
php artisan queue:listen --queue=queue_name --timeout=0  
OR
php artisan queue:work --queue=queue_name --timeout=0 //this will run forever
```

Note:
  May be you can try supervisord,beanstakd for manage queue

For more info refer [this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queues)

Comment: Can you please clarify your last command? Same this is happening when I Create a job and dispatch the job on queue. I haven't used the `php artisan queue:work --queue=queue_name --timeout=0` command because I haven't got what is it doing and why do I need it.

Comment: Update my answer may help anything. Or go through the link in the answer once

Comment: So, I need a queue listener or worker to process my job. But who will run the `queue:listener` or `queue:worker` command?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need all advantages of proper queue, which come at a price, it may be sufficient to use [terminate middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/middleware#terminable-middleware). It will do the job after response was sent to the browser.

Comment: Will it affect any further request to the server?

Comment: @Al-ImranAhmed, Not sure I get the question. Do you have any particular concerns?

Comment: Suppose, I hit an url, I got the response then after providing the response the server is processing another task(which is in terminable middleware). In that task I have a `sleep(1000*10)` command. In the mean time, if another request is made to server, will the previous request's terminable task(sleep) affect the new request.

Comment: I still don't get what do you mean by *affect the new request*. It wont affect it any worse than in original implementation in the question. Usual restrictions for shared resources apply, e.g. if you write-lock a file in one thread and try to write to the same file in another request before the first one releases the lock, then yes, it will affect. Otherwise 2 requests are handled by 2 different processes, which do not interfere. `terminate` does not change how php work, it just flush output buffer before executing its code.

Comment: I got it thanks. By the word `affect` I asked as the previous request is `sleep` command and something(may be PHP) is sleeping for a certain time. So, in that sleeping time if another request come, will the new request have to wait until the old request's sleeping time is over. I mean all this by a small word `affect`. My bad.

Comment: Yes, usual limitations. E.g. if you reached `max_requests` for all children. Again, it is no different from sleeping in controller, service, or vanilla php. There is no magic in `terminate` middleware. It is just the code that's executed after output buffer is sent to the client. In all other ways, it is the same old php.