# Laravel DB::beginTransaction causing other transaction locked

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, locking

In classic php I have 2 process files

1) `process1.php`  => To lock row for .table InnodB.

2) `process2.php` => To read another row from the same table

I have played with `START TRANSACTION AND COMMIT` in PHP/MySQL and it is working properly as what I want.
What I want is the `process2.php` can select another record eventhough the `process1.php` is still running and locking some row.

Unfortunately it does not work in Laravel where my other process was locked until the first process completed eventhough the second process is selecting another table.

Please help me to figure out this issue.

```
DB::beginTransaction();
$rs = DB::table('test_iap')->where('content', 'waiting')->lockForUpdate()->get();

$sql = "update test_iap set content='Updated' where id=1";
DB::connection('mysql_pencil_main')->update(DB::raw($sql));
sleep(10);# To allow testing at different file process

DB::commit();
```

Comment: at the beginning you mentioned process2 is reading from the same table and later you say: "even though the second process is selecting another table". which one is the case?
Also it is better to include code for both processes.

Answer (score 1):

use `sharedLock()` instead-of `lockForUpdate()`.  A shared lock prevents the selected rows from being modified until your transaction commits. see more  description  [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#pessimistic-locking)

```
DB::beginTransaction();
$rs = DB::table('test_iap')->where('content', 'waiting')->sharedLock()->get();

$sql = "update test_iap set content='Updated' where id=1";
DB::connection('mysql_pencil_main')->update(DB::raw($sql));
sleep(10);# To allow testing at different file process

DB::commit();
```

Comment: Thank yo for the comment. This is the theory that is very successful if the second process is not Laravel. The problem is if the second process is Laravel, it block the other process until the first process completed. Is there any configuration need to do to the laravel. I tested in classic PHP or mysql terminal is really working fine.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is from **sleep**. I tried the same script without any locks or transactions and the other apis still waiting until the 10 seconds end.
Please take a look at this question: 
[How to sleep PHP(Laravel 5.2) in background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41205924/how-to-sleep-phplaravel-5-2-in-background).

If you want to let the sleep, you can run another program on another port like:

`php artisan serve --port 7000`

and send the second request on that that port..