# Laravel queue randomly not dispatching

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to dispatch jobs from a controller, but sometimes the queue works, and sometimes it will execute the code immediately. On the other hand, dispatching from a command works fine, so I wonder what the difference could be.

Things that I have tried:

- I tried database and Redis connections and got the problem for both connections
- Without running queue listen/work, the job will randomly execute, so listen/work cannot be the problem
- Checked webserver/PHP log for errors, no result
- Something goes wrong before the static dispatch function. **When I put a die in the static dispatch function, it will sometimes kill the app, and sometimes it will still run decode in the handle immediately....**

vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bus/Dispatchable.php

```php
public static function dispatch()
{
    die('xxx');
    
    return new PendingDispatch(new static(...func_get_args()));
}
```

I'm trying to find what happened before the dispatch function, but I cannot find any function that executes before the static handle function. I have the feeling that something is crashing in PHP and alternatively execute the job immediately, but I cannot find where that happens in the core.

**Controller**

```php
class CreateTestJob
{
    public function __invoke(Request $request)
    {
        TestJob::dispatch(rand(0, 999999));
    }
}
```

**Job**

```php
class TestJob implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public function __construct($test)
    {
        $this->test = $test;
    }

    public function handle()
    {
        sleep(30);

        echo 'done';
    }
}
```

I also tried to create a syntax error in de handle function of the TestJob so that I can see the stack trace, but it shows "1 unknown frame". I wonder what that is

[image: Stacktrace]

Comment: If you dispatch using "sync" driver, what happened? What driver are you using for your queue? Are you sure the issue is from the dispatch, and not the handler?

Comment: Also, can you implement the "failed_job" table to check if any issue is reported here, or in laravel logs, or in webserver/php log? Do you have any rate limiting in place? Or specific configuration on your job delays/timeouts? How do you execute task? Another server? Supervisor? Just CLI for testing? Wich command?

Comment: The static function `dispatch()` doesn't accept any parameters.

Comment: @Mtxz when i use the sync driver then it will execute the code immediately. There is nothing in the failed_job because it will run the code immediately which means it doesnt use the queue. There are no errors in the web/php log
. I used php artisan queue:work and php artisan queue:listen in the cli and supervisor.

Comment: Is there anything about your environment that may result in multiple incarnations of your code that may have fallen out of date, like Opcache or a collection/load-balancer?

Comment: I think it's because of sleep(). laravel will sleep for 30 seconds and try queue again and it will work . Try it without sleep.

Comment: Check that [https://stackoverflow.com/a/41206034/10828488](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41206034/10828488)

Comment: I see you're using the `SerializesModels` trait. Perhaps sometimes your input, a.k.a. your collection/model contains data that isn't serializable (to a string) so it will dispatch it directly?

Comment: Job _might_ be executed immediately if there is nothing else for the worker to do?
Check queue processing by NOT running the worker. Dispatch multiple jobs.  Check that they are in the queue then run the worker.

Answer (score 2):

1. you can check fail_jobs table if there is any error while running your job.
2. The job will be immediately executed only when you use synchronous driver or synchronous dispatch(for use in local development).

   `<?php Somejob::dispatchSync();`
3. Jobs on Redis and database connection will be executed only when you run queue worker.

   `php artisan queue:work`